# How to custom gunicorn logger formatter?

Tags: django, logging, gunicorn, supervisord, formatter

I use gunicorn + nginx + supervisor +django . I got this log :

```
[2016-11-09 19:27:53 +0000] [14676] [DEBUG] GET /audit/list_pay/
```

this is my start gunicorn cmd:

```
gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --workers 4 --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 --log-level debug --log-file=-
```

my supervisor conf:

```
[program:cmdb]
command= /usr/local/cmdb/cmdb_gunicorn_start
directory=/usr/local/cmdb
startsecs=0
stopwaitsecs=10
autostart=false
autorestart=false
stdout_logfile=/data/logs/cmdb_gunicorn.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

I put `--access-logformat "%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s %(s)s %(b)s"` append the gunicorn start cmd , but it not work .

I try another gunicorn log params , but they not work .I do not know which logger parameters can be used .

what i should do to get more logger info .

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape each percent with another percent, per the [Nginx docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=escape%20percent).